# Including subitems in query using LINQ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework-4.1

Using mvc3 and entity framework 4.
In sql server, the "Steps" table has foreign key constraint to "Question" via stepID.
The query (below) steps includes any associated questions.

```
var steps = from b in db.Steps.Include(s => s.Questions)
            orderby b.StepOrder
            select b;

return View(steps.ToList());
```

I want to also pull "answers" associated to questions. 
In sql server, the "Questions" table has foreign key contraint to "Answers" via questionID.
How do I change the query to include answers associate to questions which are associated to steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `Select` the grandchildren inside the `Include`

```
var steps = from b in db.Steps.Include(s => s.Questions.Select(q => q.Answers))
            orderby b.StepOrder
            select b;

return View(steps.ToList());
```

See *Eagerly loading multiple levels* section in the [Loading Related Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj574232) EF tutorial.

Comment: Nemesv, one last question how do I access answers?

Comment: Figured it out...IGNORE my last comments..thank you for your help